# Add an row programmaticaly to an UWP DataGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is it possible to programmaticaly add a row to an UWP DataGrid? I'm trying to do so when an user clicks a button so he can fill the row and when it finishes editing that row data saves on the object that's binded to the datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to programmaticaly add a row to an UWP DataGrid?

Sure, you just need to bind DataGrid itemsource with [`ObservaleCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) object, and insert new empty item in the button click method. then start edit the each column for the row. it will save the data automatically.

For example

```
<controls:DataGrid
    x:Name="MyDataGrid"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
    AlternatingRowForeground="Gray"
    AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
    AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="True"
    CanUserResizeColumns="True"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"
    ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
    FrozenColumnCount="0"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyClasses, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"
    MaxColumnWidth="400"
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
    RowGroupHeaderPropertyNameAlternative="Range"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
        <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
        </Style>
    </controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>

    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Name}"
            Header="Name"
            Tag="Name" />
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Complete}"
            Header="Complete"
            Tag="Complete" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Add" />
```

**Code behind**

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> MyClasses { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyClasses.Add(new Item { Name = "Nico", Complete = false });
    MyClasses.Add(new Item { Name = "LIU", Complete = true });
    MyClasses.Add(new Item { Name = "He", Complete = true });
    MyClasses.Add(new Item { Name = "Wei", Complete = false });
    MyClasses.Add(new Item { Name = "Dong", Complete = true });
    MyClasses.Add(new Item { Name = "Ming", Complete = false });

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyClasses.Add(new Item());
}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```